# NICE DISPLAY in PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, html, view

i want to know how seperate each line of what i make appear on the screen.

I try `<br> \t (spacebar)` but it wont work.
it appears like that 
Ex:

```
USER PASSWD 
aUser aPasswd
```

i want it appears like that:

```
USER         PASSWD
aUser        aPasswd
```

More clear, no?! :D

here is my code `$tab` is the title : USER    PASSWD

```
 function db_select($prep, $username, $tab){        
      error_reporting(-1);  //Activer le rapport de toutes les genres d'erreurs
      $querycon = "SELECT $prep FROM info_compte WHERE username = '$username'";
     if(!$response = mysql_query($querycon)){
        echo "Il n\'y a aucun $username dans la base de données";
    }
     else{
            echo $tab.'<br>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($response, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                foreach($row as $item)
                {
                    echo $item.' ';
                }
        }
    return $response;   
}//db_select
```

Comment: I think this is just an HTML/CSS problem, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your output in `<pre>` tags:

```
echo "<pre>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($response, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 foreach($row as $item) {
   echo "$item\t";
 }
 echo "<br>\n";
}
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put it into a table

```
<table>  
<tr><td>Username</td><td>Passwd</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $username ?></td><td><?php echo $passwd ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

This way it will have equal spacing, and you can adjust the width of the cell

UPDATE (assuming your pulling both username and password):

```
echo "<table>";  
echo "<tr><td>Username</td><td>Passwd</td></tr>";
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$key.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```